# docker run interactive with conda environment already activated

Tags: docker, dockerfile, conda

I'd like to create a docker image such that when you run it interactively, a conda environment is already activated.

Current state:

```
docker run -it my_image
(base) root@1c32ba066db2:~# conda activate my_env
(my_env) root@1c32ba066db2:~#
```

Desired state:

```
docker run -it my_image
(my_env) root@1c32ba066db2:~#
```

More info:

In my Dockerfile, I include all the necessary `RUN` commands to install conda, create the environment, and activate the environment. Relevant portions reproduced below.

```
SHELL [ "/bin/bash", "--login", "-c" ]

...

# Install miniconda.
ENV CONDA_DIR $HOME/miniconda3
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
    chmod +x ~/miniconda.sh && \
    ~/miniconda.sh -b -p $CONDA_DIR && \
    rm ~/miniconda.sh
# Make non-activate conda commands available.
ENV PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH
# Make conda activate command available from /bin/bash --login shells.
RUN echo ". $CONDA_DIR/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.profile
# Make conda activate command available from /bin/bash --interative shells.
RUN conda init bash

# Create and activate the environment.
RUN conda env create --force -f environment.yml
RUN conda activate my_env
```

When I run this, `conda activate my_env` seems to run and succeed. But when I enter interactively with `docker run -it`, the activated env is `(base)`.

Additionally, I've tried having the last command be `CMD conda activate my_env`, but then it just runs that and does not enter interactive mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each `RUN` statement (including `docker run`) is executed in a new shell, so one cannot simply activate an environment in a `RUN` command and expect it to continue being active in subsequent `RUN` commands.

Instead, you need to activate the environment as part of the shell initialization. The `SHELL` command has already been changed to include `--login`, which is great. Now you simply need to add `conda activate my_env` to `.profile` or `.bashrc`:

```
...
# Create and activate the environment.
RUN conda env create --force -f environment.yml
RUN echo "conda activate my_env" >> ~/.profile
```

and just be sure this is after the section added by Conda.

Comment: For interactive containers, out of sixteen bazillion solutions out there, this is the one that nailed it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The following code in my Dockerfile does what you describe:

```
# Install anaconda
RUN cd $HOME && wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.10.3-Linux-x86_64.sh && bash Miniconda3-py38_4.10.3-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
# Create env
RUN $HOME/miniconda/bin/conda init bash
RUN $HOME/miniconda/bin/conda env create -f my_env.yml
# Activate conda environment on startup
RUN echo "export PATH=$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH" >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo "conda init bash" >> $HOME/.bashrc
RUN echo "conda activate my_env" >> $HOME/.bashrc
SHELL ["/bin/bash"]
```

results in:

```
(my_env) root@e5fe69843fa1:/#
```

when running an interactive container.

Remember to change all instances of `my_env` to the name of your conda environment.