# micromamba installation in Nvidia/cuda-runntime docker image does not work

Tags: docker, mamba

due to the new licensing policy for conda, we have to use mamba as alternative. I am in the process of migrating my docker files but have issues getting micromamba properly installed. The base docker is as follows

```
ARG CUDA=11.1.1
FROM nvidia/cuda:${CUDA}-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu18.04
ARG CUDA
```

Then I install all curl etc via apt-get. Installation of micromamba is done via

```
RUN curl -Ls https://micro.mamba.pm/api/micromamba/linux-64/latest | tar -xvj bin/micromamba
RUN export MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX=./micromamba  # optional, defaults to ~/micromamba
RUN eval "$(./bin/micromamba shell hook -s posix)"
RUN micromamba activate
```

during the build I get the following errors;

```
RUN micromamba activate
 ---> Running in ccee400f407d

'micromamba' is running as a subprocess and can't modify the parent shell.
Thus you must initialize your shell before using activate and deactivate.

    To initialize the current  shell, run:
        $ eval "$(micromamba shell hook --shell=)"
    and then activate or deactivate with:
        $ micromamba activate
    
To automatically initialize all future () shells, run:
    $ micromamba shell init --shell= --prefix=~/micromamba

Supported shells are {bash, zsh, csh, xonsh, cmd.exe, powershell, fish}.
```

Any advice?

Comment: Each RUN command is a separate shell process. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64325388/570918

Comment: Thanks merv, I was not aware of that. Will try and find out the proper configs for micromamba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using an image from [`mambaorg/micromamba`](https://hub.docker.com/r/mambaorg/micromamba). These images all have `micromamba` installed and some helper scripts that make it easier to activate your environments in different contexts. The images with `cuda` in the tag are derived from `nvidia/cuda` images.

If you want a Ubuntu 18.04 image, try:

```
mambaorg/micromamba:bionic-cuda-11.6.2
```

or if you are up for something a bit more cutting edge, try:

```
mambaorg/micromamba:jammy-cuda-12.1.0
```

Please see the [documentation for these image](https://micromamba-docker.readthedocs.io/) and the [corresponding GitHub repo](https://github.com/mamba-org/micromamba-docker). If you need a base image other than those provided on Dockerhub, then see the [instructions for how to add `micromamba` to other images](https://micromamba-docker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#adding-micromamba-to-an-existing-docker-image).

Full disclosure, I am the lead maintainer of the `mambaorg/micromamba` image series.

Comment: I have tried to mambaorg/micromamba:focal-cuda-11.8.0 as base image but apt-get install throws error ```E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)```

Comment: mambaorg/micromamba defaults to a non-root user. Add a "USER root" line directly before your "RUN apt-get ..." command and then at the end do "USER $MAMBA_USER" after the "RUN apt-get ..." command.

Comment: The docker RUN command does not seem to find the mamba installs (e.g. pip3), despite ```MAMBA_DOCKERFILE_ACTIVATE=1```. could this be because I ran the micromamba installs as root instead of $MAMBA_USER?

Comment: I just tested installing python via micromamba as root, setting `USER $MAMBA_USER` and then doing `ARG MAMBA_DOCKERFILE_ACTIVATE=1` and `RUN pip3 install requests`. It worked for me.  Can you please submit an issue with your full Dockerfile over at https://github.com/mamba-org/micromamba-docker

Comment: Just submitted them on GitHub. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: As I posted on github, your `SHELL ...` statement is clobbering the shell configuration done within `mambaorg/micromamba`

Comment: Those images are great, but I need other OS's for reasons, so it would be nice to have some guidance on how to make micromamba work in other containers than those.

Comment: @BenFarmer please see https://micromamba-docker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#adding-micromamba-to-an-existing-docker-image