# Interactively run docker image as a non-root user with already activated conda environment

Tags: docker, dockerfile, conda

**Note:** This thread is an extension to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323539/docker-run-interactive-with-conda-environment-already-activated), however, I would need a solution that also works when you run the container with `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)`

**Question:** I would like to create a docker image with a conda environment in it. The conda environment should be automatically activated as soon as I run the image interactively as a container. On top of that, it is necessary for me to run the docker container with my host's user id and user group by using `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)` (I don't have root rights on my machine and [therefore I wouldn't be able to modify/delete files](https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15) that were created by container processes if I don't pass the `-u` flag to `docker run`). The problem here is, that the user inside the container has no home directory so there's also no `.bashrc` or other files that one could use to activate the environment for this user. Is there any other way to automatically activate the environment without modifying those files?

1.) Create a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV CONDA_DIR="/opt/miniconda-latest" \
    PATH="/opt/miniconda-latest/bin:$PATH"
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
           bzip2 \
           ca-certificates \
           curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    # Install dependencies.
    && export PATH="/opt/miniconda-latest/bin:$PATH" \
    && echo "Downloading Miniconda installer ..." \
    && conda_installer="/tmp/miniconda.sh" \
    && curl -fsSL -o "$conda_installer" https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && bash "$conda_installer" -b -p /opt/miniconda-latest \
    && rm -f "$conda_installer" \
    && conda update -yq -nbase conda \
    # Prefer packages in conda-forge
    && conda config --system --prepend channels conda-forge \
    # Packages in lower-priority channels not considered if a package with the same
    # name exists in a higher priority channel. Can dramatically speed up installations.
    # Conda recommends this as a default
    # https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html
    && conda config --set channel_priority strict \
    && conda config --system --set auto_update_conda false \
    && conda config --system --set show_channel_urls true \
    # Enable `conda activate`
    && conda init bash \
    # Clean up
    && sync && conda clean --all --yes && sync \
    && rm -rf ~/.cache/pip/*
```

2.) Build the image from Dockerfile using `docker build -t conda_activate:test .`

3.) Run the image as a container using:

`docker run -ti --rm -u $(id -u):$(id -g) conda_activate:test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum solution to this problem is to add these lines to your Dockerfile:

`ENV PATH="/path/to/miniconda/envs/env_name/bin:$PATH"`

This will set the default environment. Note that this does not solve any "cosmetic" issues, so it still might look like the base environment is activated (e.g. `(base) user.name@hostname: ...`)

For more information, see this link:

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/12858#issuecomment-1640020652